# expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions with shape(1, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow

After I fit my machine learning I am trying to predict a new one. Image named demo1.jpg

What I expected get new feature into my library:

My details:

```
RTX 2080
Tensorflow 1.13.1
Cuda 10.0
```

I'm using tf.keras and I'm getting following error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1)

My full code:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="-1"

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pickle
import cv2
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow import keras

IMG_SIZE = 50

def prepare(file):
    img_array = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))

    predictdata = tf.reshape(new_array, (1, 50, 50))
    predictdata = np.expand_dims(predictdata, -1)
    return predictdata


pickle_ind = open("x.pickle", "rb")
x = pickle.load(pickle_ind)
x = np.array(x, dtype=float)
x = np.expand_dims(x, -1)

pickle_ind = open("y.pickle", "rb")
y = pickle.load(pickle_ind)

n_batch = len(x)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(50, 50, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x, y, epochs=1, batch_size=n_batch)
prediction = model.predict([prepare('demo1.jpg')], batch_size=n_batch, steps=1, verbose=1)

print(prediction)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do below changes:

```
def prepare(file):
    img_array = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    return np.expand_dims(cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)), -1)

model.fit(x, y, epochs=1, batch_size=n_batch)
model.predict(np.array([prepare("demo1.jpg")]), batch_size=n_batch, steps=1, verbose=1)
```

**Issue:** `tf.reshape` returns a tensor not a numpy array. Then the `expand_dims` adds a dimension and returns a single element np array (the element being the tensor).

Rather return a image as 3D np array then create a batch of images for prediction.

Comment: but then i predict a new photo (demo1.jpg) it is a dog. but my machine learning say (1.) 0 = dog, 1 = cat...

Comment: @fredy you have to train the model before you can make predictions using it `model.fit(x, y, epochs=1, batch_size=n_batch)`.  I only answered the prediction parts as you have mentioned in  your question that you have an issue with prediction  `I am trying to predict a ....`

Comment: look at my code again, look at bottom of my code. i have model.fit

Comment: i don't understand what you say. i have (model.fit and model.predict)

Comment: you say i need new question ?

Comment: @fredy please do `model.fit` before the `model.predict` . I think there is a confusion as I did not include it in the solution. I have updated it now. In case you are indeed fitting the model, then check how good the trained model accuracy is on the validation data.

Comment: i have model.fit first then model.predict. look at my code in question

Comment: 24946/24946 [==============================] - 38s 2ms/sample - loss: 7.9693 - acc: 0.5001
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 40ms/step
[[1.]]

Comment: @fredy accuracy of your model is pretty bad `acc: 0.5001` is saying 50% of your predictions are wrong. It is as good as random guessing. You have to train it for longer or change the model architecture.

Comment: so i just change (epochs=1) to (epochs=10) e.g.?

Comment: Epoch 10/10
24946/24946 [==============================] - 30s 1ms/sample - loss: 7.9693 - acc: 0.5001 (it still says 0.5001 hmm)

Comment: will you have my x.pickle and y.pickle ?

Comment: will you test it for me if you get the file? x.pickle and y.pickle

Comment: @fredy sure. Share the pickle file (github or some other way)

Comment: hello, can i send my own homeiste in here? or break the rules?